# Convert Date to UK for Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, date

Please help, this has been driving me crazy for months.

I am querying data from an MS SQL DB that is not very well constructed and has many challenges. One particular challenge that has so far got me stumped is presenting the date in a format easily understood by users and recognised by Excel as a date (not text)

To begin, the date in this DB is stored as 'yyyymmdd' varchar(8). I want to convert to dd/mm/yyyy (UK format). I have achieved this using many different functions as follows...

```
FORMAT(CAST(20180728 as date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')

CONVERT(date,20180728,120)

SUBSTRING(20180728,7,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(20180728,5,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(20180728,1,4)
```

All of which provide the desired result, but when viewed in Excel they are seen as text so filtering by a range becomes a challenge.

I then found the following function that is recognised by Excel as a date but is not a user friendly display...

```
CONVERT(smalldatetime, 20180728, 103)
```

This returns the format as 2018-07-28 00:00:00 despite reading on all sites I have visited that the code 103 should return in UK format.

I appreciate that once the data is in excel it can be reformatted but i'm trying to avoid this and enter direct to Excel with no further user interference.

Hoping for a great answer

Comment: `smalldatetime` (and other datetime types) don't *have* a format. You attempted to convert a *string* to a `smalldatetime` and told it (via 103) that the *string* was formatted as a UK datetime. You weren't correct but it managed to do the conversion okay anyway.

Comment: Thanks @DTU, you say I wasn't correct, do you have a suggestion for the correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double convert. First converting to a `(small)datetime`, which as I say in the comments doesn't *have* a format<sup>1</sup>, and then convert it back to a string in your desired format:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10),
CONVERT(smalldatetime,'20180728',112) --This string is yyyymmdd
,103) --I want a string as dd/mm/yyyy
```

However, I doubt the results will be much different if Excel hasn't been happy with some of your other efforts.

---

<sup>1</sup>Internally a `smalldatetime` type is made up of two 16-bit integers (range 0-65535). One of these stores the number of whole days elapsed since 1st January 1900. The other stores the number of minutes past midnight. The astute will notice that 5 bits are wasted by this plan, but it's *simple*.

Recognize that when you're dealing with formatting, you're almost always looking at the *conversion* between two datatypes, where one of those datatypes is a string. The string doesn't "have" a format - it contains the *results* or characters that are purported to *match* a format. And the other data type often doesn't "have" a format either. It's the conversion process itself that requires formats.

Also recognize that you don't often view data directly. If you e.g. run a query in SQL Server Management Studio, you don't see the *data*, you see the data as SSMS has processed it, and one of the inevitable steps it has to take with any non-string data it's going to display is to convert it to a string. And the conversions it applies to do that aren't under your control but importantly, don't tell you what the actual data *is*.

Comment: Thats a really good explanation, thanks again @DTU. You are correct, as i am then converting back to a string excel says no. at lest i have a much better understanding of the whole thing now.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column in excel to format as a date.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, trying to avoid this if possible

Comment: You can't avoid it.  This is an Excel problem, not a SQL problem